# How to use other subclasses in a method

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am using the `Gadget` class that takes in the `initialize` method (make, model, price, weight, height, width). There are three subclasses of `Gadget`: `IPhone5s`, `IPhone6s`, and `IPhone6`. I need help with an inherited method `createiPhone`.

I am struggling to get other subclasses printed in the method `createiPhone`. I want to take `iPhone6s` and `iPhone6Plus` when the user creates `iPhone6s`, and then output the prices into the method `createiPhone`. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be useful as well.

#### Function from AppleStore:

```
def createiPhone (model)

    a = Gadget.new(:iPhone, model, 99.00, 4.87, 2.31, 3.95);

    @@reveune_earned += money_made(a.price) 
    @@no_of_products +=1 
     puts " A  #{model} that cost $ #{a.price}0 weighing #{a.weight} ounces  "
    puts " A store having sold #{ @@no_of_products} with revenue earned #{@@reveune_earned}"
    return a 
end
```

#### Derived classes:

```
class IPhone5s < Gadget
     def initialize( make)
        super( :iPhone, "5s".to_sym, 99.00, 4.87, 2.31, 3.95) #make, model, price, weight, height, width 
#, 99.00, 4.87, 2.31, 3.95, 
    end 
end 

class IPhone6s < Gadget
    def initialize( model)
        super( :iPhone, "6s".to_sym, 199.00, 4.55, 5.44, 2.64) 

    end 

end 

class IPhone6Plus < Gadget
    def initialize( model)
        super( :iPhone, "6s".to_sym, 299.00, 6.07, 6.22, 3.06) 

    end 
end
```

#### Tester:

```
puts "here is your iphone5s"
p = AppleStore.new()
iphone5 = p.createiPhone(:iPhone5s)
puts "here at the AppleStore"
```

#### Output:

```
here is your iphone6
  A  iPhone5s that cost $ 99.00 weighing 4.87 ounces
 A store having sold 3 with revenue earned 1348.0
here at the AppleStore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). For example here's the code which may work in your case:

```
class AppleStore

  @@reveune_earned = 0
  @@no_of_products = 2

  def createiPhone(model)
    a = Gadget.create(:iPhone, model, 99.00, 4.87, 2.31, 3.95);
    @@reveune_earned += money_made(a.price) 
    @@no_of_products +=1 
    puts " A  #{model} that cost $ #{a.price}0 weighing #{a.weight} ounces  "
    puts " A store having sold #{ @@no_of_products} with revenue earned #{@@reveune_earned}"
    return a 
  end

  def money_made(price)
    @@no_of_products*price
  end
end

class Gadget
  GADGETS = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = {} }

  attr_reader :price, :weight, :height, :width

  def initialize(price, weight, height, width)
    @price, @weight, @height, @width = price, weight, height, width
  end

  def self.create(make, model, price, weight, height, width)
    if klass = GADGETS[make][model]
      klass.new(price, weight, height, width)
    else
      raise 'Gadget is not registered.'
    end
  end

  private

  def self.register_gadget(make, model)
    GADGETS[make][model] = self
  end

end

class IPhone5s < Gadget
  register_gadget :iPhone, 'iPhone5s'
end 

class IPhone6s < Gadget
  register_gadget :iPhone, 'iPhone6s'
end 

class IPhone6Plus < Gadget
  register_gadget :iPhone, 'iPhone6sPlus'
end
```

Test it:

```
puts "here is your iphone5s"
p = AppleStore.new()
iphone5 = p.createiPhone('iPhone5s')
puts "here at the AppleStore"
```

Output:

```
here is your iphone5s
 A  iPhone5s that cost $ 99.00 weighing 4.87 ounces
 A store having sold 3 with revenue earned 198.0
here at the AppleStore
```